# How to create a global variable defined in Test Listeners with type?

Tags: java, groovy, katalon-studio

I use Katalon ([Simplify API, Web, Mobile
Automation Tests](https://www.katalon.com/)) and I need to create a global variable called `objectA` in a Test Listener.

However, this variable is not a `String` but an `Object`, so I cannot used `GlobalVariable` feature.

There is a way to defined and store this object from a Test Listener to use it anywhere and anytime in my project?

Thanks in advance,
Regards,

**Possible solution:**

```
def map = ['ObjectA' : new ObjectA()]
GlobalVariable.Gbl_Map = map
...
def map2 = (Map) GlobalVariable.Gbl_Map
def res = map2['ObjectA'].method()
```

Comment: Java doesn't really support global variables.

Comment: Indeed, but I use Katalon which is based on Java, that's why I added Java tag. I will mentionned that in my question.

Comment: I 've never used Katalon, so maybe I'm way off, but I don't get the impression that Global Variables are limited to String only: https://docs.katalon.com/katalon-studio/docs/execution-profile-v54.html

Comment: You need to create the global variable before running the test. Give it an initial value (empty string will do). Then just update its value by running the test with test listener.

Comment: Indeed there is several types : String, Number, Boolean, Null, Test Data Value, Test Object, Range, List and Map. But not object :(

Comment: you can put into map or array just anything

Comment: @MateMrše thanks four your answer. If I do that I cannot do something like : `GlobalVariable.objectA.method()`.

Comment: with map i believe you could do something like: `GlobalVariable.myMap.objectA = new ObjectA()` and then `GlobalVariable.myMap.objectA.method()`

Comment: @daggett indeed thanks. However, still same problem. I have to define the value type and object type is not available.

Comment: Thanks all. I updated my question with a possible solution.

Comment: another approach that works for me:  declare global variable with name `objectA` with type Null (value null), switch profile to `Script view` (the tab on the bottom), and change the value of the `objectA` variable to something that you need:
 `new Date()` for example

Comment: @daggett very nice stuff !

Answer (score 1):

In Katalon you can use their in-built function called ["profile"](https://docs.katalon.com/katalon-studio/docs/global-variables.html#define-a-global-variable):

Example:

```
if (diffInMinutes < GlobalVariable.News_updated_time ) {
         println('system is getting updated')} else {
         CustomKeywords.'errorMessage.logFailed.markStepFailed'('from 1 h,system was not updated');}
```

Screenshot: [image: global variable]